# jQuery - radio button click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is it possible to disable standard action being performed while clicking radio button? (without "disable" attr)

So when i click particular radio button, nothing happens. Tried .unbind('click') but doesnt seem to work.

Ty in advance for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) method exposed by the `event` object:

```
$("input:radio").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, this does not seem to prevent the browser from checking the radio button that is clicked first (jsFiddle is in "emergency read-only" mode, so I cannot post a demo right now).

Comment: I don't believe it's "jQuery's", it's built into the language in event handlers.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, true, it's part of DOM level 2. Answer updated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('#myradio').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: What is the reason for `preventDefault()`? As far as I have tested `return false;` is sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this.

```
$('input:radio').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/E4mz9/68/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, this will stop propagation :

```
$("#my-radio-btn").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the first time you click the radio, the checked property is set and hence it shows as checked in browser ( for the firtst time ).

So this piece of code will solve the issue

[I am using jquery library]

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
$(this).prop('checked',false);
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event.disableDefault in the function you give to jQuery click.

```
 $("#my_element").click(
function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
// the rest of your code goes here
}
);
```

Comment: Sorry (bit late now too), I meant preventDefault(), as you can see in the code I supplied.